# consistent write of many blocks with O_DIRECT

Tags: c, database, linux

I am working on a database engine for Linux and I have a question about consistency regarding writing many blocks with one system call to the kernel. I open the device with O_DIRECT.

The device writes data in blocks, depending on the hardware it could be 512,2048 or 4096. Lets say I will write 2 blocks of 512 bytes in one system call. What happens if the system is shut down exactly after the disk has written 1 block? During normal operation the write() syscall will return the size of the data written, so I could compare and generate an error when 2 values (asked vs returned) mismatch, but with power shutdown it gets complicated. It is even more complicated since the kernel might send write requests to the device not in order that you told it to, so the tail of the request may be written before the head and then you have a power off.

Consider that a database engine writes a transaction log. Lets say a transaction is about 4096 bytes, the engine will need to write 8 blocks of 512 bytes. Suddenly we have power shutdown and only half of the request was written. How databases handle these issues? I suppose to get around this you would first need to write the amount of blocks you intend write to another location on the disk. Once you received correct return value, you may write your data. Then, after receiving confirmation, you must send another write to disk updating the info that all the blocks you wanted to write were actually written successfuly. So, this would require 3 write operations, and if the kernel is doing writes on disk from another processes, this will most likely result in 3 seeks. Too inefficient.

I am looking for a way to achieve a consistent write of many blocks with only one write operation to disk. (one write() syscall) Is this possible?

Comment: Why not just have enough battery or capacitor charge that you have time to detect power failure and stop the server cleanly?

Comment: @R.. , actually this a good idea. With only having an UPS I could  cache the auxiliary disk blocks, and write the actual data with one seek. Will not work for everyone, but that's a good solution to provide fast day to day operation while having a backup in case of emergency.

Answer (score 0):

Modulo some speed hacks, the write twice behavior you described is exactly what databases do.  It's called [write-ahead logging](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Write-ahead_logging), and it involves a single buffer that is written in sequential order by operations, and occasional flushing of memory buffers to disk with a corresponding flush entry written to the log.  Then, when the database system starts running, it checks the log for entries that may not have been flushed to disk, and flushes those values to disk (since the entries are in the log).

This can actually be more performant than writing the data immediately.  The log is a sequential file, so appending data to it doesn't require a seek, only rotational latency.  Furthermore, you don't have to write the data to the actual data files immediately, since you can always recover it from the log.  Then, when there aren't any requests coming in, you flush the data to disk and write a flush entry to the log.  This way, the only time that the DBMS seeks are 1) when the system is otherwise quiet and 2) when the DMBS runs out of memory for holding the modified data.  As long as you have enough memory in your machine, the disk without very many seeks at all, and those seeks happen when the DBMS isn't busy anyway.

Answer (score -1):

You need to first shutdown your database engine before shutting down the system!.. When you shutdown the engine, it should first finish all the writes, sync (flush the buffers) and bring the engine to a normal halt. You can also include a command in your system shutdown script to shut the engine down first, before shutting down the system.